# How to call function every second or when element is loaded if it take (this) as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select element and I am calling function `onclick` it is working perfectly, but I want to call this function when element is loaded but because it select element can be created dynamically, I want to call the function getPrice that should take this.value as parameter when the element appears or to call it every second, how can I do this?

```
<select class="form-control item" name="items[]" onclick="get_price(this.value)">
// Options
</select>

function get_price(item) 
{   
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getData.php",
      data: {item: item},
      success: function(data) {
        // do stuff
      },
    }); 
}
```

Comment: use `setTimeout()` - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "it select element can be created dynamically"?
It would be helpful if you can include a working snippet of the issue (Ctrl+M). If you can give a more complete example of your issue, it will be easier to help you find a good solution.

Comment: I'm not certain exactly what the problem is that you're trying to solve, however I can tell you that you should definitely not be making AJAX calls every second, unless you're trying to DDOS your own server.

Comment: I meant I need to use this.value because there will be many select elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because it select element can be created dynamically

You could attach the event from the JS code :

```js
//JSUT FOR DEMO START
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.item').append('<option>Dynamic option</option>');
}, 500);
//JSUT FOR DEMO END


function get_price() {
  console.log('Perform ajax request with item : ' + $(this).val());
}

$('.item').change(get_price);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control item" name="items[]">
  <option>Static option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't need a delegated event handler on the select just because you append some options at runtime...